# CanCan, what does passing a block to the can method in Ability#initialize do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, authorization, cancan

This is my Ability.rb file:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user.permissions.each do |permission|
      can permission.action.to_sym,
          permission.thing_type.constantize {|thing| thing.nil? || permission.thing.nil? || permission.thing_id == thing.id}
    end
  end
end
```

thing is a polymorphic association. I'm trying to understand how passing a block to can works. I've searched throughout the wiki for CanCan but haven't been able to find an explanation.

Comment: What are "permissions" return, and what is you purpose? It's a bit hard to judge from the question.

Comment: This was just an example. I just want to know what passing a block to the can method does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a block to cancan allows you to implement more complicated permission checks that depend on the state of the object itself.

When it's just attributes on the object you want to check then you don't need a block:

```
can :read, Project, :active => true
```

allows a user to only read active projects. If you need to call project's `editable` method then you could instead do

```
can :read, Project do |project|
  project.editable?
end
```

At the point that cancan checks whether you can read a particular project (ie when the `before_filter` fires or you call `can? :read, some_project) then the block gets called

There's a page about this on the wiki: [Defining abilities with blocks](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities-with-Blocks).

In your case it looks like the intent is that the permission object can either grant access to a whole class (if `thing_type` is set but `thing_id` is null) or to a specific instance of the class.

However the code you've posted doesn't actually do this. Of the 2 ways of passing a block, `{}` binds more tightly than `do...end` so the block isn't passed to `can` at all. It is instead passed to `constantize`, which ignores it. You could disambiguate this by using parentheses, or by using `do...end`

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for that explanation, especially about the block binding.